# passing var to url when click button via javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```
<input type="text" name="my_sld" style="width: 55%" value="">
<br />
<select name="my_tld" style="width: 20%">
    <option value="com" label="com"> .com </option>
    <option value="net" label="net"> .net </option>
    <option value="org" label="org"> .org </option>
</select>

<script>
var sld = my_sld();
var tld = my_tld();
var domain = sld + tld;
</script>

<button go to = http://example.com/check/ + domain + >
```

how to make my_sld + my_tld go to mysite when i click the button via javascript?

for example = http://example.com/check?domain=thedomainname.net

Comment: Try looking into `window.location`. You may have to have your button call a javascript function through onclick, which then sets the location.

Comment: Give to the input text and to the select an id attribute then load the value with jquery. You can append that value to the url

Answer (score 7):

You should do like this..

First provide any ID to button :

```
<button id=“test” value=“click">
```

Then in javascript you should do like:

```
<script>
$("#test").click(function(){
      var sld = my_sld();
      var tld = my_tld();
      var domain = sld+tld;
      window.location.href="http://example.com/check?domain="+domain;
 })
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<script>
function redirect() {
    window.location = 'http://example.com/check/' + sld + tld;
}
</script>
<button onclick='redirect();'>
```

or with unobtrusive and still pure javascript

```html
<button id='redirect'>
<script>
    document.getElementById('redirect').onclick = function() {
        window.location = 'http://example.com/check/' + sld + tld;
    };
</script>
```